# SwiftUI / AppKit Interaction between embedded app (e.g. extension) and main app

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit

In my SwiftUI / AppKit application I have a main app and an extension (in my case a Finder Sync Extension) and I would like to send some data from my extension to the main application (call a method in the main app for example).

The extension is embedded in the main application.

I have actually found a working solution to this issue but its not really optimal. My solution works by opening a URL in the extension and accepting the data in the main app by using an URL Scheme. (This is far from optimal, though because I need to encode the object I actually want to pass a JSON, URL encode it and then decode it on the other side)

To sum up, what is the best/easiest way to send data/interact between an embedded application (e.g. an extension) and the main application?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to do this, but most likely, you'll want the main app to write data somewhere the extension can get to it, and then read it from the extension.

You should read through the docs for `FileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:)`, which has some discussion of the app group's directory in MacOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412643-containerurl

Once you've got a directory that both the main app and extension can read to, you can write whatever you need there and then read it at the appropriate time from the extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works great if I need to have some data generated by the main app and use it in the extension (or vice-versa). But what if I need to simply call a function in the main app (my extension creates a new entry in the context menu of the finder, which is supposed to call some sort of function in the main application). Do I need to resort to watching the folder you mentioned and if a certain file appears, the main app calls the function itself?